# Let $f: X \to S^n$ be a map that is not surjective. Show that $f$ is nullhomotopic.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, solution-verification

I'd like to ask for some checking on my solution.

Since $f$ is not surjective, there exists $p \in S^n$ such that for all $x \in X, f(x) \neq p$.

Define $F: X \times I \to S^n$ to be:

$$
\begin{cases}
F(x,t) = f(x)  & x \in X, 0 \leq t < 1 \\
F(x,1) = p
\end{cases}$$

I want to show that this is the homotopy that we need. Clearly $F$ satisfies the condition that $F(x,0) = f(x) \text{ and } F(x,1) = p$. So I just need to show that it's continuous.

Let $U \subset S^n$ be open. It's here that I'm a bit hesitant since I need to distinguish between two cases.

**Case 1:** $p \in U$. Since $f$ is continuous, we have that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in X, and so $\pi_X^{-1}(f^{-1}(U))$ is open in $X \times I$, where $\pi_X: X \times I \to X$ is the projection onto $X$. And so $f^{-1}(U) \times [0,1] = \pi_X^{-1}(f^{-1}(U))$ is open in $X \times I$.

Now $F(\pi_X^{-1}(f^{-1}(U)))= F(f^{-1}(U) \times [0,1) \cup f^{-1}(U) \times \{1\}) = f(f^{-1}(U)) \cup \{p\} = U \cup \{p\} = U$. So indeed $F = \pi_X \circ f$, and so $F^{-1}(U) = \pi_X^{-1}(f^{-1}(U))$ is open in $X \times I$ and we are done.

**Case 2:** $p \notin U$. A similar argument as above would work if we had $\pi_X^{-1}(f^{-1}(U)) = f^{-1}(U) \times [0,1)$ (instead of $f^{-1}(U) \times [0,1]$), but I don't see how we can have that.

Also why do we need $f$ to be surjective here?

====================================================================

**Edit:** it's been pointed out to me that the function $F$ that I defined is not continuous. Could this be the reason why I ran into the problem in the second case?

Comment: $F$ is not continuous in $t$ unless $f(x)=p$.

Comment: In that case $f$ factors through $S^n\setminus\{p\}\cong \mathbb R^{n}$ which is contractible.

Comment: @JustinYoung how do we know that $f$ only leaves a single point of $S^n$ out, but not multiple points that are disconnected?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the map $X\to S^n\setminus \{p\}$ is surjective or not, any more than it matters if a map $X \to \mathbb R^n$ is surjective or not, to show that it is nullhomotopic.

Comment: Does this work for all $n$? I can't see how that'd work for $n = 1$.

Comment: It does, $S^1\setminus \{p\}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I mean $S^1$ with more than one point removed.

Comment: Again, it does not matter if a map $X\to \mathbb R $ is surjective or not, it is nullhomotopic.

Answer (score 3):

The $F$ that you defined is not continuous.

Since $f$ is not surjective, consider the stereographic projection $H$ centered at $p$ which is not in the image of $f$ and define:

$G(t,x)=H^{-1}(tH(f(x))$.

Comment: My familiarity with stereographic projection is pretty limited. I can see that the map you defined works, but don't see why. Do we need specific definition for the map? Also, what's the property of the map that makes use of the special point $p$?

Comment: the idea is the fact that is the map is not surjective, its image is contained in a contractible space.

Comment: So the stereographic map that you use is to show that $S^n \setminus \{p\}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, which is contractible? But how do we know that $f$ only leaves a single point of $S^n$ out, but not multiple points that are disconnected?

Comment: @TsemoAristide when $t = 0$, we have $G(0,x) = H^{-1}(0) = - p$. So just to be sure, I assume the original definition of $G: X \times I \to S^n$ is: $G(x,0) = - p$, and $G(x,1) = f(x)$?